# Cakephp specify fields being saved?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp, insert

In my model, I have a field called difficulty, but no matter what value i give it, a value of 1 is saved to the database.

I did a datadump on the model before I did a save() and this is what I see:

```
Array
(
    [title] => testtt34
    [serves] => 32
    [prep_time] => 32
    [cooking_time] => 32
    [difficulty] => 4
)
```

But the sql query cakephp generated is this:

```
INSERT INTO `recipes` (`title`, `serves`, `prep_time`, `cooking_time`, `difficulty`, `modified`, `created`) VALUES ('testtt34', 32, 32, 32, 1, '2011-03-13 19:15:16', '2011-03-13 19:15:16')
```

What the heck? even though difficulty is clearly 4 in my datadump, the sql generated inserted difficulty = 1.

```
//Do some checking to make sure the data is from proper location
$this->data = Sanitize::clean($this->data);
$this->Recipe->data = $this->data;
//error checking
$this->pa($this->Recipe->data['Recipe']);
if ($this->Recipe->save())
{
    //Blah do some stuff
}
```

Comment: What's the data type of the `difficulty` field in the db?

Comment: Wow, that was dumb, it's set as TINYINT(1) ><

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I accidentally set difficulty's type as TINYINT(1) meant to do TINYINT(3), well that fixed it. Very dumb mistake.